# Add SPuser to SPGroup by defult ,after registration directly

Tags: visual-studio

I need that when the user registers on the site he should automatically be logged in to the site.

How can I do that by code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can add an SPUser programmatically into SPGroup.. Something like below:

```
 SPUser spUser = spWeb.EnsureUser(userLoginName);

 if (spUser != null)
 {
     SPGroup spGroup = spWeb.Groups[userGroupName];

     if (spGroup != null)
        spGroup.AddUser(spUser);
 }
```